# What is the time complexity of this code execution?

Tags: java, time-complexity

I have to print out the numbers of occurences of characters inside a string . I have used something like:

```
String str="This is sample string";
HashSet<Character> hc= new HashSet<Character>();
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    if(!Character.isSpaceChar(str.charAt(i))  && hc.add( str.charAt(i))  ) {
        int countMatches = StringUtils.countMatches(str, str.charAt(i));
        System.out.println(str.charAt(i)+" occurs at "+countMatches  +" times");
    }
}
```

It is a kind of solution, but how do I analyze the *time complexity*? I am beginner so please guide me through the learning process.

Comment: What do you think the time complexity is? Can you give a reasonable explanation?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem as per my understanding time taken to complete the `execution` . Not that much i can say the reason why i have putted here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, if you are looking for a decent introduction to complexity analysis, the following one looks pretty good:

- [A Gentle Introduction to Algorithm Complexity Analysis](https://discrete.gr/complexity/) by Dionysis Zindros.

I recommend that you read it all, carefully, and take the time to do the exercises embedded in the page.

---

The complexity of your code is not trivial.

On the face of it, the loop will execute N times, where N is the length of the input string.  But then if we look at what the loop does, it can do one of three things:

1. if the character is a space, nothing else is done
2. if the character is not a space, it is added (or re-added) to the hashmap
3. if the character was added, `countMatches` is called.

The complexity of doing nothing is `O(1)`.

The complexity of adding an entry to the map is `O(1)`.

The complexity of calling `countMatches` is `O(N)`, because it is looking at every character of the string.

Now, if we think about what the code is doing, we can easily identify the best and worst cases.

- The best case occurs when all N characters of a string are a space.  This gives `O(N)` repetitions of a `O(1)` loop body, giving a best-case complexity of `O(N)`.
- The worst case occurs when all N characters are different.  This gives `O(N)` repetitions of an `O(N)` loop body, giving a worst-case complexity of `O(N^2)`.  (You would think ... but read on!)

What about the average case?  That is difficult if we don't know more about the nature of the input strings.

- If the characters are randomly chosen, the probability of repeated characters is small, and the probability of space characters is small.
- If the character are alphabetic text, then the spaces are more frequent, and so are repetitions.  Indeed, for English text characters are likely to be limited to upper and lowercase Latin letters (52) plus a handful of punctuation characters.  So you might expect about 60 map entries for a long string and performance that converges rapidly to `O(N)`.

Finally, even the worst-case is not *really* `O(N^2)`.  A String is a sequence of `char` values, and Java `char` values are restricted to the range 0 to 65535.  So after 2^16 distinct characters, all characters must repeat, and thus even the worst-case goes to `O(N)` as `N` goes to infinity.

(I did mention that this was non-trivial?   )

Comment: @Stephen C thank you so much for detail explanation .

Comment: You are welcome.  But please read the linked article as well.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do here is reason how many steps have to be taken in relationship to the length of the String.

For every character in the String it has to call `countMatches` once. Every call of `countMatches` has to loop over every character of the String again to count them.

The other operations (determining the length of the String, adding to the HashSet, retrieving a character from a String by index, checking the whitespaceness, printing the answers) are assumed to be constant-time and do not matter.

The fact that some of the characters will be skipped (because they are  whitespace or already in the HashSet) does not reduce the complexity for an unrestricted String. You can assume the worst case of all characters being different.

So that is O(n^2), where n is the length of the String.

You can improve it to O(n) by changing your HashSet to a HashMap of counters. Then you only need a single pass over the String instead of two nested passes.

Comment: The complexity is O(n*x) where n is the length of the string and x is the size of the alphabet.

Comment: @Taemyr - Actually, the size of the alphabet is a constant (both in theory and in practice) so `O(n*x)` is `O(n)`.